# registering jquery dynamically doesn´t work

Tags: .net, jquery, scriptmanager

I want to register a jquery-script dynamically on a master page,
but it doesn´t work, can anybody help me?

I got the script in a folder Materials/Scripts from the root of my web application,
and my master page looks like

```
public partial class Application : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, this.GetType(), "jquery",
            VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Materials/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"));
    }     
}
```

But this never works. Using

```
<script src="../../Materials/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

works fine.

Comment: I'm curious why you are trying to register it dynamically. Are you trying to load and unload client scripts depending on what page people are visiting? Or is there another reason for doing this?

Comment: @Jas - because relative paths aren't handled correctly in Master Pages for script Files.

Comment: good question. I think, in my project I don´t really need to do it, but I saw this method in a different project of our´s, and in general I think you have more control over the scripts.

Comment: Try replacing `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(` with `ResolveUrl(`

Comment: No, doesn´t help either, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `ScriptManager` to add a script reference, it adds the `SCRIPT` tag to the `BODY` of the `HTML` page instead of the HEAD section. If you have any jquery code running on `$(document).ready()` it won't work, because jQuery is not loaded yet.

View the HTML generated by the `aspx` page and see where your jQuery code is and where the `<script>` tag referencing `jQuery` is.

One way to get around this is to add your javascript at the bottom of the document instead of the `HEAD`.

Another option, if you still want to keep your code in the `HEAD`, is to use window.onload instead of `$(document).ready()` for example:

```
window.onload = function() {
 ... your jquery code here
}
```

Comment: Ups, the dynamic registering of the script actually works, but NOT on the Master-Page. I get a JS error if I try to execute a script there. The script is in the body of the page.